# How to reposition svg along the path

Tags: html, css, svg, css-animations

I need to make the note traverse along the path that is drawn, i found a way in by translating the path to the starting position of the note. But is there a workaround by which I can keep the position of the path fixed yet make the note traverse along the path.

**My code**

```
<svg width="900" height="900" viewBox="0 0 900 900" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <g >
        <path id="motion" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" class="st0" d="M0,306c0,0,155-108.6,313.8-65.3s123.7,101,256.7,105.2S733.1,191.2,792,188.2" />
    </g>
    <g id="car" transform="translate(-100,150)">
        <path id="note" fill="red"transform="scale(.5,.5)" transform="translate(0,0)" d="M248.8,306.8c0,0-24-7-28.5,11c0,0-3,16,21,16.5c0,0,19.5,2.3,18.5-28.8s0-61.2,0-61.2s42,9,19,31.5c0,0,17-1,13.5-23c0,0-7.5-20-43-22L248.8,306.8z" />
    </g>

    <animateMotion xlink:href="#car" dur="5s" begin="click" fill="freeze" repeatCount="indefinite" origin="(0,6)">
        <mpath xlink:href="#motion" />
    </animateMotion>
</svg>
```

[JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/8omxq2qp/)